# How does TypeScript's core.ts build without a overload error?

Tags: typescript, overloading

These lines of code ...

```
export function sameFlatMap<T>(array: T[], mapfn: (x: T, i: number) => T | ReadonlyArray<T>): T[];
export function sameFlatMap<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, mapfn: (x: T, i: number) => T | ReadonlyArray<T>): ReadonlyArray<T>;
export function sameFlatMap<T>(array: T[], mapfn: (x: T, i: number) => T | T[]): T[] {
    let result: T[] | undefined;
    if (array) {
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            const item = array[i];
            const mapped = mapfn(item, i);
            if (result || item !== mapped || isArray(mapped)) {
                if (!result) {
                    result = array.slice(0, i);
                }
                if (isArray(mapped)) {
                    addRange(result, mapped);
                }
                else {
                    result.push(mapped);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result || array;
}
```

... exist on [line 702 of compiler/core.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4fee62844777c23cf37b6d4594f65b393b27b4dd/src/compiler/core.ts#L702) in the TypeScript compiler implementation source.

**Why does this compile without producing an overload error?**

I ask because I expect it to error for the same reason shown in the first example below -- i.e. trying to pass `ReadonlyArray<T>` to a parameter which expects `T[]`.

Why does it not produce this error:

```
src/compiler/core.ts:702:21 - error TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

702     export function sameFlatMap<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, mapfn: (x: T, i: number) => T | ReadonlyArray<T>): ReadonlyArray<T>;
```

---

If I try this in my code, then this is an overload error ...

```
export function foo<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>): ReadonlyArray<T>;
export function foo<T>(array: T[]): T[] {
  return array;
}
```

... whereas this is not an error ...

```
export function baz<T>(array: T[]): T[];
export function baz<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>): ReadonlyArray<T> {
  return array;
}
```

... and I guess that's because:

- `T[]` as an input parameter can be passed to a function which expects `ReadonlyArray<T>` as its input parameter (but not vice versa)
- The overload error checking only checks the types of the input parameters, not of the return types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [tsconfig-base.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4fee62844777c23cf37b6d4594f65b393b27b4dd/src/tsconfig-base.json) you will notice that not all strict options are enabled. Most noably for your question, `strictFunctionTypes` is not enabled.

This means that the compiler will be much more relaxed about function compatibility, alowinf function parameters to relate bivariantly (you can read more [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)). Although the PR does not mention overloads explicitly, it does affect function signature compatibility in general so it makes sense it would affect overload compatibility as well. So for example this assignment is not valid under `strictNullChecks` but valid without it:

```
let fn : <T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>) =>  ReadonlyArray<T> = function<T>(array: T[]): T[] {
  return array;
}
```